# Migrating from SafetyNet to Play Integrity API in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, google-play-console

I tried to Migrating from SafetyNet to Play Integrity API (playstore published) my flutter app.

**problem :**

Now, The Auth is working on real devices (physical devices). But, when run phone auth on real devices, It's going to `reCAPTCHA` verification. I want to remove `reCAPTCHA` verification. (Also show firbease project name in OTP SMS)

**I did these changes for migrate:**

- disabled `Android device verification api` from cloud console and enabled `Play Integrity API`
- added this codes to app level Build gradle

  ```
  dependencies {    
    // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.5.0')

    // Add the dependency for the Firebase Authentication library
    // When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
  }
  ```
- Linked firebase project to play console

> setup >> App integrity linked Google Cloud project

**What I found:**

- reCAPTCHA can work when SafetyNet or the Integrate API is not working.
- Now not available : `Android device verification api` on Cloud console

Therefore, case for this problem can be SafetyNet or the Integrate API is not working

Comment: Provided you have done everything needed and yet its not working, you should know this is a known issue and Firebase is working on it.
You could find a detailed discussion on this thread. Suggest you to read through all the comments to get a better understanding
https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/10593

Comment: Also see this [comment from Firebase team mate nohe427](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/10593#issuecomment-1528358648) on that issue from last night that the superfluous display of reCAPTCHA has been resolved.

Comment: Thank you. got it. In my case, still shows the reCAPTCHA. I unpublished the app from Play Store (because of the OTP problem). It can be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I solved my problem-

In my case It's happened because

**Play Integrity API must use the Play deployed version of your app.**

Comment: Means the version must be same as the version at Google Play Store for local development?

Comment: yes. You must use the same the version at Google Play Store for local development.

Comment: can you share more details on the configuration? I am trying to do testing on my phone my connect it directly to Android Studio. However, I got the following error.

UID: [10554]  PID: [22030] IntegrityService : Unbind from service.

Hope you can share more details on your configuration part.